# Saving data in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-applications

I'm new to coding and to Angular. Now I'm making a calculator-ish web app and I have a rating section in the footer. What I don't understand is how to save data so that it gets avialable for other users. The relevant part of the code is as under:

```js
.controller('rateController', function() {
      this.positive = 0;
      this.negative = 0;
      this.addLike = function () {
          this.positive = this.positive + 1;
          this.liked = true;
      };
      this.addDislike = function () {
          this.negative = this.negative + 1;
          this.disliked = true;
      };
  });
```

```html
      <div>
          <table style="text-align:center; font-size:1em" class="table-responsive table" ng-controller="rateController as rating">
              <tr>
                  <td>Jeg likte den!</td>
                  <td>Jeg likte den ikke!</td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                  <td><p class="likes" ng-click="rating.addLike()">+{{rating.positive}}</p></td>
                  <td><p class="dislikes" ng-click="rating.addDislike()">-{{rating.negative}}</p></td>
              </tr>
          </table>
      </div>
```

I would be very grateful if anyone could show me how to save the amount of likes and dislikes to the websites server. If you want to see how it works now, [here](https://googledrive.com/host/0B_tg4it67g1bWWFHV3hnaXVEcGs/) is the adress. The rating table is in the footer.

Comment: may be this link help you  http://www.angularcode.com/voting-system-similar-to-stackoverflow-using-angularjs-php-and-mysql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into AngularJS $http or $resource libraries. You can use those to make server calls.

I would recommend to start your controller with assigning 'this' to a named variable. That will prevent you from trouble if 'this' is assigned to something else inside some functions.

```
    $http.post('/someUrl', data, config)
          .then(function () {
               alert('success'); 
           }), function() {
               alert('something went wrong'); }
            );
```

Comment: If you have no experience in using a serverside language, I recommend looking into that first, like wizzwizz said.

AngularJS is a client-side framework.

Comment: I should probably do that, but considering this was a very small function in the footer of my app, I was more looking for a quick fix just for storing the 2 numbers: likes and dislikes. Does there excist any short and easy way for doing this @Noppey ?

Comment: Not that I know of. You need to store this in a file or database on a server.

I definitely recommend to learn a server-side language (nodeJS, PHP, Asp.Net) if you want to build apps. If you want to build more applications, you'll always find yourself needing to store certain things.

Only if you want to make applications without cross-client information, then you can use javascript localstorage (but that is storing only per client, not across clients).

Answer (score 0):

From somebody who's wanted to save data to a server for a while (but I haven't had a server!) I think the easiest thing to use is PHP. You can set up a PHP script to upvote and downvote particular things depending on the URL passed (e.g. `http://example.com/vote.php?vote=up&page=help`) and that will save votes to a file (requires more general skill) or database (requires learning more PHP). Then you can AJAX request to the PHP script, and the script could return the number of votes so far.